# Which-key: change next/previous page keybindings

Tags: which-key

This question has been edited thanks to dalanicolai.

I want to change some of the default `which-key` key binds used to turn the pages.

In `which-key.el` they are set like so:

```
(defvar which-key-C-h-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (dolist (bind `(("\C-a" . which-key-abort)
                    ;;abbreviated...
                    ("n" . which-key-show-next-page-cycle)
                    ("p" . which-key-show-previous-page-cycle)
                    ;;abbreviated...
      (define-key map (car bind) (cdr bind)))
    map)
  "Keymap for C-h commands.")
```

when I do :

```
(define-key which-key-C-h-map (kbd "z") 'which-key-show-next-page-cycle)
```

I can turn the pages ok.

but when I want to use PgUp/PgDown and do :

```
(define-key which-key-C-h-map (kbd "<next>") 'which-key-show-next-page-cycle)
```

I get: `which-key-C-h-dispatch: Wrong type argument: characterp, next`

Why can't I use those two keys?

Comment: How to achieve this for an individual prefix is explained in the [whichk-key README](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key#paging-options). Unfortunately, at first sight (I did not look into it), it seems that it is not designed to set it for all prefixes at once.

Comment: Consider reporting a bug (or enhancement request) to the maintainer of `which-key.el`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

To briefly answer your edited question also, this happens because `read-key` in `which-key-C-h-dispatch` returns a number for some characters (like 'z') and a symbol for others (like 'next'). A solution for your question is to replace the 'value' for the lexical variable `key` by

```lisp
(let ((k (read-key prompt)))
  (if (numberp k)
      (string k)
    (vector k)))
```

You can open an issue for it at which-key, where it would probably be handy to point/refer to this answer/solution.

END EDIT

Here follows an answer, following your last comment.

What you are trying works like expected. However, you should enter the keybinding correctly and use an existing command. Try

```lisp
(define-key help-map (kbd "<next>") 'which-key-show-next-page-cycle)
```

However, this only binds `[next]` in the `help-map`, if you would like a similar thing in the `C-x` `which-key-mode-map`, you could do

```lisp
(define-key which-key-mode-map (kbd "C-x <next>") 'which-key-show-next-page-cycle)
```

Comment: I do agree that it would be nice if this configuration option for paging got documented in the README. Maybe you are willing to add it to the README and create a PR (you can edit the README right on github).

Comment: Right, thank you for the correct command syntax, there's indeed an error on the README about it. 

Second command is not what i would like: i want to press `C-x WAIT help-char <next>`, not `C-x WAIT help-char C-x <next>`.

When i bind `(define-key which-key-mode-map (kbd "<next>") 'which-key-show-next-page-cycle)` it does not work.

Comment: What is `help-char`? I am not sure what you mean, but what the code does is to provide paging using `<next>` after you have pressed `C-x` (to open which key). So I would say it is just `C-x <next>`, no `wait` and no `help-char` (or at least no `help-char`, depending on what you mean with `wait`)...

Comment: Help char = `C-h`, is called that way in the manual : http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Help-Functions.html. What I meant by `WAIT` is that which key has a delay before showing up. I try again like you describe and it indeed works. But this way I must set up a new bind for each prefix in which I want to turn the pages. I edit the question to be clearer.

Comment: Maybe you did not get updated, but I have edited the answer...

Comment: Thank you for notification, indeed I missed it. Is that supposed to go here https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key/blob/master/which-key.el#L2364 ?

Comment: Exactly... replace the `(string (read-key prompt))` with the code in the answer...